# How to render a child collection in a view so that it rolls back into the parent model upon post?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Let's say I have a model hierarchy like so:

```cs
public class TabModel
{
  public PolicyModel Policy {get;set;}
}

public class PolicyModel
{
  public IEnumerable<PersonModel> Insured {get;set;}
}

public class PersonModel
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and I want to render a grid in the view with a editor for `Person Name` right in the grid.

I know that if I can just get the html to be like so:

```
<input name="Policy.Insured[0].Name" /> 
<input name="Policy.Insured[1].Name" /> 
...
etc
```

that upon post, my main model will have a policy and that policy will have some insured with names.

What in my razor do I call to make this happen automagically™?

I'd bet a *dozen* donuts there's something in the framework that knows about `Collection[N].PropertyName` when iterating over a collection but I don't know how to invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

If I put:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Policy.Insured)
```

and in the `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates` folder put a `PersonModel.cshtml`, then in that file create my editors, it works as I hoped.